# Spring boot micro-service should come up irrespective of Db status

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, microservices

What I am looking for is some suggestions on this behavior: Spring boot app(Considered as a microservice) should come up, irrespective of Db status.

Why I am doing this?
Based on my understanding of the microservice all services should be independent of each other.

I am using Spring boot with JPA (org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.7'). I am able to achieve this using the below configuration

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/xxx?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&characterEncoding=utf8&enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2&useSSL=false
    username: xx
    password: xx
    continueOnError: true
    initialize: false
    initialSize: 0
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 5000
    minIdle: 0

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
    properties:
      hibernate:   
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: none
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
```

But now the issue is I have to make hbm2ddl.auto none. Due to this, I am losing update schema functionalists which is one of the very essential functionality.

Requirement:
case 1. Service should be up and running irrespective of DB status
case 2. Jpa/Hibernate should update the database schema by comparing the existing schema with the entity mappings and generate the appropriate schema migration scripts (hbm2ddl.auto: update)

Can we achieve both? If yes how? or Do I have to compromise with one?
If I am going with only "case 1" do I have to rely on running schema updates manually or is there any other way?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried excluding **org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration**? Check out this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-disable-auto-config) to learn how to do that.

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear. Can you please give more details on requirement?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal updated the question Please take a look

Requirement:
   case 1. Service should be up and running irrespective of DB status 
   case 2. Jpa/Hibernate should update the database schema by comparing the existing schema with the entity mappings and generate the appropriate schema migration scripts (hbm2ddl.auto: update)

Can we achieve both? If yes how? or Do I have to compromise with one?
If I am going with only "case 1" do I have to rely on running schema updates manually or is there any other way?

Comment: @mrkachariker in this case (excluding DataSourceAutoConfiguration) we have to compromise on hbm2ddl.auto: update. Am I correct?

Comment: @user3093845 - this is very strange requirement. You want that services should be up and running without DB status and you are using DB in your code. As you mentioned in question that you are doing this because all microservices should be be independent and yes that is the rule but how it is related to your requirement? 

If your api is dependent on DB and DB is down then api should be down or if you don’t want to do that then keep backup DB for failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you can exclude `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration`if you wish for spring boot to ignore the status of the data source ([link on how to do that](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-disable-auto-config)). In order to still have the schema auto-generated/controlled outside of your actual db you could use something like [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/), which is used a lot in production environments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the immediate response. One question Jpa/Hibernate used to take this responsibility (hbm2ddl.auto: update) that why it needed to connect to DB before the application started.  If we are going with liquiase or flyway kind of plugin, these plugins will also be required to connect to DB. so what will be the ideal behavior if something fails while updating?

Comment: If something fails while updating you should rollback to the state before the tried out change, but I think liquibase already does that for you if you implement it correctly.

Comment: Hey @user3093845 did my answer help you in solving your issue? If so I would appreciate it if you chose it as correct!